# Android Cordova: push notification from Parse.com starts 2nd instance of App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to process push notifications from Parse when app is in background. I'm using this plugin:

- [github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin](https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin)

Also I've added `MainApplication` to initialize Parse on app launch.

```
package com.example.app;
import android.app.Application;
import com.parse.Parse;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_KEY");
        //ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

And everything worked fine except it launched the second instance of app. This action caused users not to see any data:

[image: i.imgur.com/yOvturi.png]

---

I've changed launchMode for main `CordovaApp` activity, but this didn't help:

[image: i.imgur.com/m3PyxNw.png]

---

It seems like there is a solution inside another Сordova plugin:

- [github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/notification/AbstractClickActivity.java#L89](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/notification/AbstractClickActivity.java#L89)

But I have no Android development experience and can't figure out how I can reimplement this, because my plugin hasn't any activities inside.